# wro4j and browser caching

Tags: java, caching, wro4j

I'm using WRO4j to process my less and js files, and I'm finding that the browser seems to keep caching the old files.  WRO4j has an enhancement to add a hash to the URL to bust the cache, but it looks like it hasn't been done.  What are my options to force the browser to reload the resources?  I'd like a solution that worked regardless of environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this pretty much answers my question.  WRO4J has no options available to handle this.  But using URLRewriter, adding version information to the manifest during a build, and quick view template. Then voila! A solution.

https://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/versioning_static_assets_with_urlrewritefilter

Comment: This is crazy. wro4j has many features but not this one out of the box? This is the reason I want to run jawr-like products in the first place.